# The Empty Function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I refer to the book from Deiser, Einführung in die Mengenlehre, 3. Aufl. because I wanna know if I think correctly purely based on his definitions.

1. Deiser first defines the ordered pair for any mathematical objects a,b as (a,b) = {{a}, {a,b}}. From this definition follows that even if a = $\emptyset$ then the ordered pair is just ($\emptyset$,b) = {{$\emptyset$}, {b}}. So far so good.
2. Then he defines the function as a set f if for all a, b1, b2 it holds: if (a,b1) $\in$ f and (a,b2) $\in$ f then b1=b2.
3. Then at some point he says that the empty function (f: $\emptyset$ -> A) is indeed a function.

But IS IT according to what he wrote?

Here's a counterexample: let's assume f: $\emptyset$ -> A and A = {1,2}. So f = {($\emptyset$,1), ($\emptyset$,2)}. This violates the definition of a function and therefore it shows that the empty function is at least not always a function. But I always read that the empty function is a function and it's graph is the empty set. So where does it go wrong: does Deister give bad definitions or do I think wrongly somewhere and he's innocent?

Answer (score 4):

You have confused $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$.

If the domain of $f$ is empty, then $f = \emptyset$.

Comment: If the domain of f is empty then it just means: dom(f) = $\emptyset$. If the range of f is {1,2} then we have f: $\emptyset$ -> {1,2} and I argue that it is not a function. I also don't see where I confuse emptyset and {emptyset}, can you just point to where I confuse it in your opinion?

Comment: If $f$ is a function, and $(\emptyset, 1) \in f$, then it follows that $\emptyset \in dom(f)$. But this contradicts the assumption that $dom(f) = \emptyset$.

Comment: Damn it, that's so cool. So if dom(f) = $\emptyset$ then there cannot be an ordered pair at all in f because it would contradict the empty dom(f). And so Deisers definitions of a function becomes true because its antecedens is always false if dom(f) = empty. And now it also makes sense that the graph of an empty function is empty because there cannot be any ordered pairs.

Comment: Yep, that’s it.

Comment: Just for my understanding: dom(f), rng(f) $\subseteq$ f (= what we call "function")?

Comment: @Pippen Not quite. For example, $f$ is a set of ordered pairs, whereas $dom(f)$ is just a set. What's true is that $f \subseteq dom(f) \times rng(f)$.